# open the camera in my own uiview without opening the camera application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

My Iphone application uses the camera, I have the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I wish that the camera application **will not open** and instead i'll have the camera feed in my own uiview or uiimageview is that possible?

I've tried this line of code instead of  `[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];`:

```
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

this results in an exception `[UIImagePickerController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

**Solution:**
I found [this great tutorial](http://i-software-developers.com/tag/avcapturesession/) including a code sample and a download project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following code:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (videoDevice)
{
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        if ([session canAddInput:videoInput])
        {
            [session addInput:videoInput];
            AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
            [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
            [session startRunning];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this code replace the UIImagePickerController or complement it?

Comment: In your case, yes it does

Comment: I've added the framework, but it's not recognizing the #import i'm doing, also how do i extract the image?

Comment: You must add `AVFoundation.framework`, and add the following import: `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Comment: Code works great (Xcode 9.2). By the way, don't forget to put the entry 'NSCameraUsageDescription' on plist to allow camera access..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with UIImagePickerController.  You need to add the view of the picker as a subview.

[self.view addSubview:picker.view];

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Do check Avfoundation framework ....You can use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for having your own camera feed..

Check the following Apple sample code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/squarecam/Introduction/Intro.html